# Flutter: setState not updating UI after popping

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application where the variable is initialized outside of the build function. In the build I have :

```
onPressed: (BuildContext context) async {
   await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Dialog(
         ...
         Navigator.pop()
      );
   ).then((_) => setState(() {
     print("Test is this prints");
   ));
   setState(){ flag = !flag }
}
```

The purpose of the setState is just so that the UI is updates after I close out of the dialog window. I have a util file that is makes some changes to the UI when I close out of the dialog, and I would like to see it reflected after I close out of the dialog.

For some reason, the UI is not changing even though setState should be rebuilding the widget since something changes.

When I do the .then(setState(){}), the console prints the print statement, but the UI is still not changing.

Comment: why you use flag here ?

Answer (score 0):

In which code or widget, you are using the flag variable.

If flag is not used in any of the widget then your UI will not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove multiple setState, just use one and also check usage of flag variable in your code.

```
.then((_) => setState(() {
     flag = !flag
     print("Test is this prints and updated flag value is $flag");
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

**When rebuild  by setState(), flag is also reset. So always flag is false**.

**Make it a variable inside the State class**

```
   onPressed: (BuildContext context) async {
   await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Dialog(
         ...
         Navigator.pop()
      );
   ).then((_) => setState(() {
     print("Test is this prints");
       flag = !flag
   ));
  
}
```